# devtools::document() not creating data.R man files

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

In my R package, I have documented some functions and data in the `roxygen2` format, but running `devtools::document()` only produces `.Rd` files for the functions I have documented, and not the data. Here is the entire contents of my `data.R` file:

```
#' Coordinates
#'
#' WGS84 coordinates of select communities.
#'
#' @format A data frame with 2 variables: \code{lon}, \code{lat}
"coords"
```

Shouldn't running `devtools::document()` create a `coords.Rd` file in `man/` as well?

Comment: It generally works for me when I include `@docType data` among the roxygen comments. (I also have used `@keywords datasets`, not sure if that's necessary or even useful.)

Comment: Thanks for your input! That wasn't working for me, because I made a super lame mistake I just discovered - had the data.R file saved in `data/` instead of `R/` :| works fine now, and the `@keywords` and `@docType` don't appear to be required.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but ... is `devtools` smart enough (without `@docType`) to label it so that `data(package="mypackage")` lists your `coords` frame?

Comment: Yep, looks like it is smart enough - creates the `.Rd` file with `\docType{data}` even when I don't have that in the roxygen comments. Could be because I used `use_data()` to save it, however.

Answer (score 0):

Well, discovered that I had the `data.R` file saved in `data/` instead of `R/`. Guess this could help someone eventually? Make sure things are saved properly!